# A Dependent Role has multiple principals with different values

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Enitity Framework codefirst and I have the following design

```
public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

public class DelieryRate 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int OriginId { get; set; }
    public Location Origin { get; set; }

    public int DestinationId { get; set; }
    public Location Destination { get; set; }

    public double Amount { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

I do not want to define the relationship on Location. When I update the database, it works but I get a referential integrity error when I run my seed code. I have tried to configure it using fluent api as follows

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DeliveryRate>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.Origin)
            .WithOptional()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<DeliveryRate>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.Destination)
            .WithOptional()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

When attempting to update the database I get the following error

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.ConstraintException: Referential integrity constraint violation. A Dependent Role has multiple principals with different values.
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.TableChangeProcessor.DiagnoseKeyCollision(UpdateCompiler compiler, PropagatorResult change, CompositeKey key, PropagatorResult other)
>      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.TableChangeProcessor.ProcessKeys(UpdateCompiler compiler, List`1 changes, Set`1 keys)
>      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.TableChangeProcessor.CompileCommands(ChangeNode changeNode, UpdateCompiler compiler)
>      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.d__0.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__71`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateCommandOrderer..ctor(IEnumerable`1 commands, UpdateTranslator translator)
>      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ProduceCommands()
>      at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
>      at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager entityCache)
>      at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
>      at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.SeedDatabase()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
>   An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details

Is there a better way to model the relationship between Locations and DeliveryRate.
Am I making a mistake with the fluent api bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One-to-one relationships with separate foreign keys are not supported by Entity Framework. EF maps your model with shared primary keys, that is `DeliveryRate.Id`, `DeliveryRate.Origin.Id` and `DeliveryRate.Destination.Id` must all have the same value. They probably have not in your `Seed` method which is the cause of the exception.

Shared primary keys are not useful for your model because you could never create a `DeliveryRate` that has a `Destination` different from `Origin`.

You can solve the problem by modeling the two relationships as one-to-many:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<DeliveryRate>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.Origin)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.OriginId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<DeliveryRate>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.Destination)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.DestinationId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: Hi @Slauma, what you say makes sense. I actually did not intend to have shared primary key but I thought EF would 'know' to map OriginId to Origin and DestinationId to Destination...it obviously didn't and was blowing up because both values were different. I solved the problem by using the [ForeignKey()] annotation on the foreign keys but since that achieves the exact same thing as your answer, I'll take yours. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

This error is thrown when there is a mistake in relationship mapping, it could be mapping two reationships to the same foreign key property:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TipOrder>().HasRequired(c => c.Tip).WithMany(x => x.TipOrders).HasForeignKey(x => x.TipId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
modelBuilder.Entity<TipOrder>().HasRequired(c => c.Order).WithMany(x => x.TipOrders).HasForeignKey(x => x.TipId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

both map, accidently, to TipId.